# Input field of django form not showing

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am fairly new to Django and am following the try django 1.10 series by CodingEntrepreneurs on youtube and therefore, am unable to solve the problem. I am only seeing the submit button, while the input field is not showing. Below is the code that I am working on.

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class SubmitUrlForm(forms.Form):
     url = forms.CharField(label="Submit Url")
```

views.py

```
from .forms import SubmitUrlForm

def home_view_fbv(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
    return render(request, "app/home.html", {})


class HomeView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        the_form = SubmitUrlForm()
        context = {
            "title": "Submit Url",
            "form": the_form
        }

        return render(request, "app/home.html", context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        form = SubmitUrlForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)

        return render(request, "app/home.html", {})
```

app/home.html

```
<div style= 'width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;'>
    <h1> {{ title }} </h1>
       <form method = 'POST' action = '.'> {% csrf_token %}

   {{form.as_p}}

  <input type= 'submit' value= 'Shorten' >
       </form>

</div>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from .utils import code_generator, create_shortcode
from django.conf import settings

SHORTCODE_MAX = getattr(settings, "SHORTCODE_MAX", 15)



class surlShortManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self, *args,**kwargs):
        qs_main = super(surlShortManager,self).all(*args, **kwargs)
        qs = qs_main.filter(active  = True)
        return as

    def refresh_shortcodes(self, items= 100):
        qs = surlShort.objects.filter(id__gte = 1) 
        if items is not None and isinstance(items, int):
            qs = qs.order_by('-id')[:items]
        new_codes = 0
        for q in qs:
            q.shortcode = create_shortcode(q)
            print(q.id)
            q.save()
            new_codes += 1
        return "New codes made: {i}".format(i = new_codes)





class surlShort(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    shortcode = models.CharField(max_length = SHORTCODE_MAX, unique = True, null 
= False, blank = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    objects = surlShortManager()


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.shortcode is None or self.shortcode == '':
            self.shortcode = code_generator()
        super(surlShort, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.url)
```

Comment: share your models.py

Comment: I added the models file as well, however, there weren't any changes to that according to the tutorial and it was working just fine before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your HomeView to this

```
from django.views import View
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import SubmitUrlForm

class HomeView(View):
    form_class = SubmitUrlForm
    context = {
        "title": "Submit Url",
        "form": form_class
    }
    template_name = 'app/home.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Comment: this seems to the trick, thank you for that, however, it doesn't include the title part that is to be displayed, can you please include that as well?

Comment: @shrekh use this i have updated the answer. and accept the answer if it resolve your problem

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I faced another issue, I had to re-declare context and form_class in both get and post functions because otherwise it was raising a name error, shouldn't it be able to access both these since they were declared in the same class?

Comment: yes it will access. Just change form_class = ----- and context = { '': ''}